# Binding database fields in html tables

Tags: php

Just moved from asp to php and i'm trying to display database records in a table. i've binded some fields in the view but it doesn't show up

PHP

```
<?php require_once('Connections/hey.php'); ?>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT fullname, city FROM dbo.user";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

//echo json_encode($stmt);

$a = Array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['fullname'].", ".$row['city']."<br />";
     $a[]= $row;
}

//echo json_encode($a);
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  

?>
```

HTML

```
<table width="12%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr bgcolor="#EBEBEB">
    <td width="17%"><div align="center"><strong>Fullname</strong></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do you actually have any results?

Comment: yes i get results

Comment: Is the php and html all in the same file?

Comment: yes,its all in the same page

Comment: And this has a `.php` ext? I would not see why @PaulSCoder solution would not be working. Can you do a `print_r($a)` or `var_dump($a)` on the outside of the while loop and verify you see what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is that I don't see a loop around your HTML to iterate over the extracted array `$a`
Something like this:

```
<table width="12%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr bgcolor="#EBEBEB">
    <td width="17%"><div align="center"><strong>Fullname</strong></div></td>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach ($a as $row) {?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Use loop inside of table by rows, not the full table.

Comment: I've just fixed it )